# EclipseMercurial Download

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I am trying to find and download the EclipseMercurial plugin for Spring Tools, but every place I look I can't seem to find a way to download it.

The market place won't work and seems like every updated link I find for it is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

On the [market page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mercurialeclipse), a guy is saying that the current place for the plugin is [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse/-/wikis/home) and the [update site](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse-updatesite).
Is this one a working solution or buggy too ?

Comment: I just don't know to install it onto eclipse from there

Comment: If you hover "install", it says that you can *drag to install*. More details here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=381680

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to download and install MercurialEclipse using the following link:

https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse-updatesite/-/raw/branch/default

In Eclipse do the following:

1. Window->Install New Software
2. Paste the given link in "Work with" section and hit enter
3. Select "MercurialEclipse Stable Releases" and hit next
4. Click agree to the terms and conditions, it might ask you if you really wanna install and just click "Install anyway"